# How to resolve Error in tagAssert error for Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting the error below when I try to run my Shiny Dashboard script, but I've no idea what's causing it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Error: Error in tagAssert(body, type = "div", class = "content-wrapper") :
Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.

I am not receiving any errors when I run the UI or Server components, its only when I run the shinyApp function in the final step.

Here is an subset of the data I am using:

```
structure(list(FACTOR_NAME = c("ABI", "ABI", 
"ABI", "ABI", "ABI_VEH", 
"ABI_VEH", "ABI_VEH", "ABI_VEH", 
"ABI_VEH", "ABI_VEH"), LEVEL_NAME = c("AEB1", 
"AEB2", "AEB3", "N", "1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"), EXPOSURE = c(381785, 
616864, 690655, 3447237, 27, 2410, 5779, 8451, 10850, 16383), 
    EXPOSURE_PERC = c(0.03, 0.05, 0.06, 0.28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), ACT = c(269.12, 373.94, 302.69, 248.71, 6.87, 239.6, 
    162.02, 210.18, 228.18, 187.76), PRED = c(258.55, 345.05, 
    300.93, 255.41, 203.7, 211.58, 199.49, 253.01, 227.99, 239.33
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is my current script

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

# UI 

sidebar <-    dashboardSidebar(width = 350,
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarname",
                                           menuItem("HOME", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
                                           convertMenuItem(menuItem("DASHBOARD", tabName = "dashboard", "dashboard",
                                                                    
                                                                    box(width = NULL, 
                                                                        uiOutput("factor_select")
                                                                    )
                                           ), 
                                           tabName = "dashboard"))
                               )



# Body: !! Change the comments here !!
body <- dashboardBody(
  
  #useShinyjs(),
  
  tabItems(
    tabItem("dashboard",
            
            tags$style(type="text/css",
                       ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                       ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),
            
            tabsetPanel(id="dashboard_tabs", type="tabs",
                        tabPanel("Overall AvP", value = "overall",
                                 br(),
                                 plotlyOutput("sample_graph"),
                                 br(),
                                 DT::dataTableOutput("output_table")
                        )
            )
    )
  )
)


##################################################################################################################
# Server
##################################################################################################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  # Display factor dropdown - different depending on input dataset
  output$factor_select <- renderUI({
    message("render selected_factor   \n")
    query_str = paste0("select distinct factor_name from ", oracle_dataset, " order by factor_name")
    cat(query_str)
    factor_list <- as.list(dbGetQuery(con, query_str))
    selectInput("selected_factor", "Factor:", factor_list[["FACTOR_NAME"]])
  })
  
  
  select_data <- function(){
    query_str <- paste0(
      "select factor_name, level_name, exposure_perc, act, pred ",
      " from ", 
      oracle_dataset,
      " where factor_name = '",
      input$selected_factor,
      "'",
      "order by level_name")
    
    cat(query_str)
    
    select_data <- dbGetQuery(con, query_str)
  }
  
  
  
  # This outputs the summary graph (groups all months together)
  output$sample_graph <- renderPlotly({
    
    data_to_plot <- select_data()
    
    plot_ly(data_to_plot, x=~LEVEL_NAME) %>%
    add_lines(.,y = data_to_plot$ACT, name = "Actual")  %>%    
    add_lines(.,y = data_to_plot$PRED, name = "Pred Cal") %>%    
      add_bars(type = "mesh2d", y = data_to_plot$EXPOSURE_PERC, name = "exposure", yaxis = "y2", opacity = 0.5) %>%
      layout(
        title = "Overall",
        yaxis = list(title = "Total burning cost", side = "left", rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis2 = list(title = "exposure", side = "right", overlaying = "y")
      )
    
  })
  
  
  
  
}  

shinyApp(
  dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body), 
  server = server
)
```

Comment: Hello, please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This means that you should remove all code that isn't related to the bug, and that you should provide some data that is available for everyone, which is not the case of `oracle_dataset`

Comment: I've done this now

Comment: This is not the way to provide data because it's an image, we can't copy this data easily. Please use `dput` as explained in the link I provided before

Comment: Can you please confirm if the above is ok?

Comment: I don't find the function `convertMenuItem`, what package are you using?

Comment: I am using shiny and shinydashboard

Comment: Did you use a custom function called `convertMenuItem`? I don't see it in your code. Also, in your `shinyApp()` you use `header` but `header` is not defined. Please make sure your example is *reproducible*. You should also remove the code that is not related to your problem. First, you need to narrow the problem down, and then when you have a *minimal* example, you can post it to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @bretauv, you need `header` to be defined with a `title`.  You could define

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title="Test App")
```

Also, your `convertMenuItem` is not defined.  How are you getting it?